# Uncached Lookup Performance Issue

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have inventory_history table that contains 2 millions of data, on which I am performing uncached lookup.

From source table, I am retrieving last 3 months data, which is around 300 thousand rows.

My mapping contains single lookup and is uncached (inventory_history). Lookup overide is used to retrieve data from inventory_history table, the condition columns are indexed and not using any unwanted columns.

But I see the t/m busy percentage is 100% and is like below 100. Lookup override query is executing well in database. This mapping is taking forever time. How can I tune the performance.

Don't know where the problem exists... Any suggestions ?

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(GM) = 'B' and UNITS> 100 THEN A.QTY/B.UNITS ELSE QTY END) AS QTY,
    A.TDATE as TDATE,
    A.TDATE_ID as TDATE_ID,
    A.DIST_ID as DIST_ID,
    A.PRODID as PROD_ID
FROM
    HUSA_ODS.INVENTORY_HISTORY A,
    HUSA_ODS.PRODUCT B
WHERE
    A.PROD_ID = B.PROD_ID
    AND TCODE = '10'    AND
    DISTID = ?DISTID_IN?
    AND A.PROD_ID = ?PROD_ID_IN?
    AND TDATE <= ?PERIOD_DATE_IN?
GROUP BY
    TDATE,
    TDATE_ID,
    DIST_ID,
    A.PROD_ID
ORDER BY
    TDATE DESC,
    DIST_ID,
    A.PROD_ID , TDATE--
```

Here output columns are QTY and TDATE

Answer (score 0):

Uncached lookup would hit the database for each of your 300 thousand rows coming from source. Use a cached lookup and see if you can filter out some of the data in your lookup query.